# My linked list adding method is failing

Tags: java, linked-list

Right now, my linked list program needs a crutch to work effectively. I need to start the linked list off with a (0,0,null) node because my addToFront() method's null head condition doesn't work. Can anybody help me fix this? I need to eliminate the zeroes for the program to be easier to work with later, and this little issue has caused me hours of pain. I know it's got to be an issue of losing a reference, PLEASE help me out!

The output is currently correct for the add() method because I have implemented a crutch method to kill the zero node of the polynomial, but I really want to learn what I am doing wrong with my addToFront() method. It's the bottom-most method, I know for a fact the if(head==null) portion is failing because if I do not initialize the first node of a list and therefore bypass it, I get returned an empty list. Thank you so much for your help in advance!

```
public Polynomial add(Polynomial p)
{   
    Polynomial newPoly = new Polynomial();
    newPoly.poly = new Node(0,0,null);
    Node curr = this.poly;
    Node curr2 = p.poly;
    float co;
    int deg;

    while(curr!=null && curr2!=null)
    {
        if(curr.term.degree == curr2.term.degree)
        {
            co = curr.term.coeff + curr2.term.coeff;
            deg = curr.term.degree;
            curr=curr.next;
            curr2=curr2.next;
        }
        else if(curr.term.degree > curr2.term.degree)
        {
            co=curr.term.coeff;
            deg = curr.term.degree;
            curr=curr.next;
        }
        else
        {
            co=curr2.term.coeff;
            deg=curr2.term.degree;
            curr2=curr2.next;
        }
        if(co!=0)
        {
            addToFront(co,deg,newPoly.poly);
        }
        // addToBack(co,deg,newPoly.poly);
        // System.out.println(newPoly.poly.term.coeff);
    }
    while(curr!=null)
    {
        co=curr.term.coeff;
        deg=curr.term.degree;
        curr=curr.next;
        if(co!=0)
        {
            addToFront(co,deg,newPoly.poly);
        }
    }
    while(curr2!=null)
    {
        co=curr2.term.coeff;
        deg=curr2.term.degree;
        curr2=curr2.next;
        if(co!=0)
        {
            addToFront(co,deg,newPoly.poly);
        }
    }




    System.out.println("Addition completed");


    killFirst(newPoly);
    newPoly = reverse(newPoly);
    killFirst(newPoly);
    return newPoly;
}









/**
 * Returns the polynomial obtained by multiplying the given polynomial p
 * with this polynomial - DOES NOT change this polynomial
 * 
 * @param p Polynomial with which this polynomial is to be multiplied
 * @return A new polynomial which is the product of this polynomial and p.
 */
public Polynomial multiply(Polynomial p) 
{
    Polynomial newPoly = new Polynomial();

    newPoly.poly = new Node(0,0,null);

    Node curr = this.poly;
    Node curr2 = p.poly;
    Polynomial tempPoly = new Polynomial();

    //for(curr=this.poly;curr!=null;curr=curr.next)
    while(curr!=null)
    {
        float x1 = curr.term.coeff;
        int y1 = curr.term.degree;
        tempPoly.poly = new Node(0,0,null);

        while(curr2!=null)
        {
            float x2 = curr2.term.coeff;
            int y2 = curr2.term.degree;

            addToFront(x1*x2, y1+y2, tempPoly.poly);
            newPoly = newPoly.add(tempPoly);
            curr2=curr2.next;
        }
        curr=curr.next;
    }

    return newPoly;
}


/**
 * Evaluates this polynomial at the given value of x
 * 
 * @param x Value at which this polynomial is to be evaluated
 * @return Value of this polynomial at x
 */



public Polynomial reverse(Polynomial p)
{
    Polynomial newPoly = new Polynomial();
    newPoly.poly = new Node(p.poly.term.coeff,p.poly.term.degree,newPoly.poly);
    while(p.poly!=null)
    {
        addToFront(p.poly.term.coeff,p.poly.term.degree,newPoly.poly);
        p.poly=p.poly.next;
    }
    return newPoly;
}

public void killFirst(Polynomial p)
{
    p.poly = p.poly.next;
}



public float evaluate(float x) 
{
    Node curr = this.poly;

    int hornerCount = 1;

    float horner = x;

    float sum = 0;
    while(curr!=null)
    {
        if(curr.term.degree==0)
        {
            sum = sum + curr.term.coeff;
        }
        else if(curr.term.degree==1)
        {
            sum = sum+(curr.term.coeff*horner);
        }
        else if(curr.term.degree>hornerCount)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<curr.term.degree-hornerCount;i++)
            {
                horner = horner*x;
            }
            System.out.println("horner ="+horner);
            sum = sum+(curr.term.coeff*horner);
            hornerCount = curr.term.degree;
        }
        curr=curr.next;
        System.out.println("+ "+sum);
    }

    return sum;
}


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public String toString() {
    String retval;

    if (poly == null) {
        return "0";
    } else {
        retval = poly.term.toString();
        for (Node current = poly.next ;
        current != null ;
        current = current.next) {
            retval = current.term.toString() + " + " + retval;
        }
        return retval;
    }
}

private void sort(Node head)                                        // CURRENTLY BROKEN!!!!!!!!!!
{ 
    Node temp; 
    Node prev;
    Node curr = head; 
    while(curr.next != null)
    { 
    if(curr.term.degree < curr.next.term.degree) // deg is smaller or greater 
        {//swap
            temp = curr; //save first element
            curr = curr.next; //set first element to second
            temp.next = curr.next; //set next of first to third
            curr.next = temp; //set second element to the first that we saved before
        }
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr.next; //move to next element
    }
}

private void addToFront(float coeff, int deg, Node head)
{
    // System.out.println("Hello");

    if(head==null)
    {
        System.out.println("List empty, creating new node");
        head =  new Node(coeff,deg,head);
        System.out.println(head.term.coeff);
    }
    else
    {
        Node n = new Node(coeff, deg, head.next);
        // System.out.println(n.term.coeff + " and "+ n.term.degree);
        head.next =  n;
    }


}
```

Comment: will creating a sentinel head node solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the caller of `addToFront` does not know that the value of `head` was changed inside the method, because `head` is a local variable. The caller can only see if a property of a passed object changed.

This is how it works (in a simplified example):

**Step 1: Before function call:**

```
     myObject                                      Object.name   Object.whatever
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|       4       |               |               |     name      |    whatever   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
        1               2               3               4               5
        |                                               ^
        +-----------------------------------------------+
```

The reference to `myObject` lies at adress 1 in the RAM. This reference says: "The properties of myObject are at address 4 onwards".

**Step 2: At function call with non-null parameter:**

```
    myObject          head                         Object.name   Object.whatever
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|       4       |       4       |               |     name      |    whatever   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
        1               2               3               4               5
        |               |                               ^
        |               +-------------------------------+
        |                                               ^
        +-----------------------------------------------+
```

When you call `addToFront`, a new address will be assigned for the reference to `head`, because head is an object. In this case, the address 2 was assigned for the reference to `head`. Address 2 now says: "The properties of `head` are at address 4 onwards".

This is why it affects the caller, if a property of a passed object is changed. If `head` was to change its `name` property, the address 4 would be changed. If later `myObject.name` was called, the content of address 4 would still be set to the new value.

**Step 3: At function call with null parameter**

```
    myObject           head
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|     null      |      null     |               |               |               |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
        1               2               3               4               5
```

The reference to `myObject` at address 1 just says: "There is no object, the properties are nowhere". This gets copied to `head`.

**Step 4: Just before exit of function**

```
    myObject          head                         Object.name   Object.whatever
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|     null      |       4       |               |     name      |    whatever   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
        1               2               3               4               5
                        |                               ^
                        +-------------------------------+
```

When something is assigned to a local object variable, only the local variable's reference is updated in RAM, but original reference is not changed. Because the the new reference in the local variable is not copied back to the original variable, your function call does not perform as expected.

---

To solve your problem, I present you with two options:

**1. Always return head and assign it somewhere:**

*Method signature:* `public Node addToFront(...)`

*Call:* `newPoly.poly = addToFront(co,deg,newPoly.poly);`

This works because returning and assigning the new reference in `head` to the original refrence is exactly like automatically copying a changed reference back to the original.

**2. Pass a `Polynom` object instead of a `Node` object**

*Method signature:* `public void addToFront(float coeff, int deg, Polynom polynom)`

Add this line at the very beginning of the method: `Node head = polynom.poly;`

This may mean, that you cannot use the method as intended in some places anymore. Check if you pass something else than `somePolynom.poly` into the method at any point. If this is the case, you cannot use this approach.

This works because now the content of `head` is not a local variable (i.e. parameter), but a property of a passed object.